# using for loop for vba

Tags: vba, excel

Run the below code in loop 35 times and... also replace the file1 with increament value and also increment Rannge("D6") as range("D7") and so on .

Use for loop and iterate 35 times increamenting file1 and d6 cell

```
Windows(File1).Activate

Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Range("A1:B1").Select
ActiveCell.Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(27961, 0).Range("A1").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Result"
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C1").Value = "Year"
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-2],4)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row)


Dim year As Integer
year = InputBox("Fill in year")
Dim week As Integer
week = InputBox("Fill in week")

Cells(1, 4) = "YEAR"
Range("C2:C" & Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("D2").Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Cells(1, 5) = "Values"
Cells(2, 5).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC[-1]=" & year & ",RC[-3]=" & week & "),1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Row)

  Range("D:D").Select

With Selection
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
.Value = .Value
 End With

Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1]:R[98576]C[-1])"
ActiveCell.Select

Cells(2, 6).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Penetrace Macros.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Book1withCount").Activate
Range("D6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Windows("Penetrace Macros.xlsm").Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Windows(File1).Activate
Sheets("Result").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Workbooks(File1).Close SaveChanges:=False
Windows("Penetrace Macros.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: Is there a question in your question?

Comment: i want to run this above code in loop that is my question and also increament the mentioned file1 as file1,file2 etc

Comment: Have you tried putting your code into a `For j = 1 To 35` `Next j` block? Please try it yourself first, and don't hesitate to come back if you encounter any problem.

Comment: Dim loop_ctr As Integer
Dim cell_ctr As Integer
For loop_ctr = 1 To 3
For cell_ctr = 6 To 8

Dim filename As String
filename = 'File' & loop_ctr

Windows(filename).Activate                                        but here how do i mention like file1 within Windows activate. as i am concatenating fileand variable value but it doesnt read as file1

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this? Idea would be something like this.

```
Dim FileNo As String

For i = 1 To 35
FileNo = "File" & i
Windows(FileNo).Activate

'Rest of the code
Next
```

Comment: i tried the same thing Dim loop_ctr As Integer
Dim cell_ctr As Integer
For loop_ctr = 1 To 3
For cell_ctr = 6 To 8

Dim filename As String
filename = "File" & loop_ctr

Windows(filename).Activate    this gives me an error at windows(filename).Activate

Comment: Hi, I think you need to use the extension as well. like: Windows(Filename & ".txt").Activate. Beside this you need the related file to be open while running the code, if it is not open it will not work as I know.